Create arrow UDF in duckdb
How do you create a simple UDF in DuckDB that operates on a pyarrow object?
For an MRE, this is an attempt to re-implement a sqrt function via pyarrow. DuckDB merely gives the cryptic error listed below.

import pyarrow as pa
import duckdb

def test(x):
    return x.compute.sqrt()

duckdb.create_function(
    'test',
    test,
    type = 'arrow',
    parameters = [ int ],
    return_type = float,
)

N = 1000
duckdb.sql(f"""

    create table t (a int);
    insert into t (a) select * from generate_series(1, {N});
    alter table t add column b float;
    update table t set b = test(a);

""")

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/w/Codin/duckdb_rust_udf/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    duckdb.create_function(
TypeError: create_function(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (name: str, function: function, return_type: object = None, parameters: duckdb.duckdb.typing.DuckDBPyType = None, *, type: duckdb.duckdb.functional.PythonUDFType = <PythonUDFType.NATIVE: 0>, null_handling: duckdb.duckdb.functional.FunctionNullHandling = 0, exception_handling: duckdb.duckdb.PythonExceptionHandling = 0, side_effects: bool = False, connection: duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection = None) -> duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection

Invoked with: 'test', <function test at 0x100237d90>; kwargs: type='arrow', parameters=[<class 'int'>], return_type=<class 'int'>


I think you need to use Type Annotations:

https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/function.html#type-annotation

Otherwise, you need to use the types from duckdb.typing, e.g. INTEGER, FLOAT, etc.
import duckdb
import pyarrow.compute as pc

def arrow_udf(x: int) -> float: 
    print(f"{type(x)=}")
    return pc.sqrt(x)

duckdb.create_function(
    "arrow_udf",
    arrow_udf,
    # [duckdb.typing.INTEGER], <- needed if not using type annotations
    # duckdb.typing.FLOAT,
    type = "arrow"
)

duckdb.sql(f"""
from (from generate_series(1, 10) t(A))
select arrow_udf(A)
""")

type(x)=<class 'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray'>

┌────────────────────┐
│    arrow_udf(A)    │
│       double       │
├────────────────────┤
│                1.0 │
│ 1.4142135623730951 │
│ 1.7320508075688772 │
│                2.0 │
│   2.23606797749979 │
│  2.449489742783178 │
│ 2.6457513110645907 │
│ 2.8284271247461903 │
│                3.0 │
│ 3.1622776601683795 │
├────────────────────┤
│      10 rows       │
└────────────────────┘


This does not compute on a pyarrow object. This is missing the core of my question. It should NOT take an int. It should take a pyarrow object.

It does compute on a pyarrow object. If you read the documentation that I linked to, duckdb inspects the signature and translates int into duckdb.typing.INTEGER for you. I added a debug print, you can see x is a ChunkedArray.

Your example works on main, I think this might have been an issue with diverging stubs and implementation.
Which was recently switched to be generated to fix issues like this.
You could install the nightly build to test this out, or wait for 0.10.3 to be released

Can you give a working example, or give a working example of how to run on "main"?

You can install the nightly wheel with pip --pre https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/?version=main&environment=python

Do you mind simply spelling out the steps of a working example? The trick with a lot of this stuff is the steps people usually leave out.
